Python-Polars: Select rows and use as headers with separator
Since Polars doesn't work with multi-index headers like Pandas does, I'd like to know if there's a native way to do the following:
My current implementation has to go through Pandas first and then convert it to a pl.DataFrame.
# ----- Multiindex DataFrame -----

arrays = [["A", "A", "B", "B"], ["one", "two", "one", "two"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
pandas_multiindex_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], columns=index)
print(pandas_multiindex_df)

    A       B    
  one two one two
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8

Note: This simulates an input excel that is separated by headers, so I will always have the data like this
They way y work is:

Flat the pandas_df

def multiindex_to_flatted_header(df: pd.DataFrame, sep: str = "-") -> pd.DataFrame:
    flat_columns = [f"{col[0]}{sep}{col[1]}" for col in df.columns]

    df_flat = df.copy()
    df_flat.columns = flat_columns

    return df_flat

pandas_flatted_df = multiindex_to_flatted_header(pandas_multiindex_df)
print(pandas_flatted_df)

   A-one  A-two  B-one  B-two
0      1      2      3      4
1      5      6      7      8


move to polars

polars_flatted_df = pl.from_pandas(pandas_flatted_df)
print(polars_flatted_df)

shape: (2, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ A-one ┆ A-two ┆ B-one ┆ B-two │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
│ 5     ┆ 6     ┆ 7     ┆ 8     │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

# Do stuff with polars performing operations


Back to pandas

pandas_flatted_df_2 =polars_flatted_df.to_pandas()

def flatted_to_multiindex_header(df: pd.DataFrame, sep: str = "-") -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [col.split(sep, 1) if sep in col else [col, ""] for col in df.columns]
    )
    return df


pandas_multiindex_df_2 = flatted_to_multiindex_header(pandas_flatted_df_2)
print(pandas_multiindex_df_2)

    A       B    
  one two one two
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8

Note: I'm going back to pandas only because I need the resulting excel to have a presentation, but this step is not necessary
The question is: Is there any way to do the same (Flatten an excel_file/pandas_multiindex) with polars? like, use_rows_and_join_with_any_separator_and_use_as_header.
I think doing this on my way could cause performance issues when use large datasets, with a polars implementation, will be boost.

Beside the point, but you can use pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays() instead of having to use a zip with .from_tuples().

Beside the point, but you can use df.set_axis() to avoid having to explicitly copy df in multiindex_to_flatted_header().

Kindly share a sample excel file

You can read the excel file twice, once to create a DataFrame of header rows and the second time to get the actual data. Then you use the header df to get the column names, and then set the second df’s column names to that.
# %%
import polars as pl

# create dummy data; requires xlsxwriter
excel_df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        ("A", "one", "1", "5"),
        ("A", "two", "2", "6"),
        ("B", "one", "3", "7"),
        ("B", "two", "4", "8"),
    ]
)
excel_df.write_excel("./Book1.xlsx", include_header=False)

# read data; requires fastexcel
N_HEADERS = 2
headers_df = pl.read_excel(
    "./Book1.xlsx", read_options={"header_row": None, "n_rows": N_HEADERS}
).select(pl.all().str.join("-"))
data_df = pl.read_excel(
    "./Book1.xlsx",
    read_options={
        "header_row": None,
        "skip_rows": N_HEADERS,
        "dtypes": "int",  # optional; values are read in as strings
    },
)
data_df.columns = headers_df.row(0)

data_df

shape: (2, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ A-one ┆ A-two ┆ B-one ┆ B-two │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
│ 5     ┆ 6     ┆ 7     ┆ 8     │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘


It works!
removing  # "dtypes": "int",  # optional; values are read in as strings
it keeps the original dtypes
